# Calling a method on array iteration, from an object - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, oop

What I'm trying to do, is iterate through an array (Which in my case is a MySql result), and output it, but also do something else with the data at the same.

Doing this using procedural methods is easy - just put it in the foreach loop.

But, I'm wondering if there is a way that it could be integrated into the object.

So, say for example, I wanted to put the first field into a session, I could do this:

```
<?php
    class MyClass {

        public $myArray=array();

        public function __construct() {

            //..
            //Mysql query as $stmt
            //..
            $this->myArray=$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        }

    }

    $obj=new MyClass;
    $i=0;
    foreach($obj->myArray as $row) {
        ?>
            <!-- Output HTML formatted data -->
        <?
        $_SESSION[$i]=$row['firstfield'];
        $i++;
    }
?>
```

But, then that takes the task away from the class.

I could put a foreach loop in the class, like so:

```
<?php
    class MyClass {

        public $myArray=array();

        public function __construct() {

            //..
            //Mysql query as $stmt
            //..
            $this->myArray=$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $i=0;
            foreach($this->myArray as $row) {
                $_SESSION[$i]=$row['firstfield'];
                $i++;
            }

        }

    }

    $obj=new MyClass;

    foreach($obj->myArray as $row) {
        ?>
            <!-- Output HTML formatted data -->
        <?
    }
?>
```

But, now we have 2 loops on the same data-set. Doubling the time to do the same task.

Is there a way to create a method to do something when the array is being looped through? Effectively making it so that the data-set would only have to be looped through once ...

**Edit**

Also, forgot to mention, the reason I can't build the HTML within the object, is because it will be used on different pages with different HTML layouts.

Comment: Constructive feedback would be much appreciated along with the down-vote :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this

```
<?php
    class MyClass {

        public $myArray=array();
        public $htm = NULL;

        public function __construct(&$format=NULL) {
            //..
            //Mysql query as $stmt
            //..
            $this->myArray=$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $i=0;
            foreach($this->myArray as $row) {
                switch ($format) {
                  case 'Page1' :
                     $this->htm .= $this->format1($row);
                     break;
                  case 'Page2' :
                     $this->htm .= $this->format2($row);
                     break;
                  default:
                     $this->htm .= $this->format_default($row);
                }
                $_SESSION[$i]=$row['firstfield'];
                $i++;
            }
        }

        private function format1($row) {
           return // formatted html
        }

        private function format2($row) {
           return // formatted html
        }

        private function format_default($row) {
           return // formatted html
        }

    }

    $obj=new MyClass('Page1');

    echo $obj->htm;
?>
```

Alternatively you could subclass MyClass with as many subclasses as you need for the formats you require.

```
class myBaseClass {

    public $myArray=array();

    public function __construct() {

        //..
        //Mysql query as $stmt
        //..
        $this->myArray=$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    }

}

class format1Class extends myBaseClass
{
    public $htm;

    public function __construct() {
        parent::_construct();

        $i=0;
        foreach($this->myArray as $row) {
            $this->htm .= // format specific to this class

            $_SESSION[$i]=$row['firstfield'];
            $i++;
        }
    }
}

class format2Class extends myBaseClass
{
    public $htm;

    public function __construct() {
        parent::_construct();

        $i=0;
        foreach($this->myArray as $row) {
            $this->htm .= // format specific to this class

            $_SESSION[$i]=$row['firstfield'];
            $i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Now depending on which format you require in any script you instantiate the required class.

```
$obj = new format2Class();

echo $obj->htm;
```

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned, It's because the object is being used on different pages that have different html layouts. I'll update my question ...

Comment: Ok so try my second attempt now I have all the relevant information

Comment: Yeah I guess this is the only way to go ... @RyanVincent has mentioned the observer pattern, but personally think it's a little OTT for what I need ... I was trying to keep all HTML formatting out of my objects, but I guess I've been defeated Lol ... Thanks

Comment: Well you could always consider subclassing MyClass with X classes that are HTML format specific. then you just instantiate the correct class for the page layout you want.

Comment: See the alternate suggestion, maybe that fits your requirements better